# Integrating Javascript Command Shell Into a Web Browser?

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement the Javascript command shell in the browser for the user to be able to press a ‘run code’ button to execute the code  right in the browser  (like code sandbox in Eloquent Javascript):

[image]

Are there any libraries that I can use to implement it?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need a library to do what you want.  You can simply read the code from the DOM element and then pass it to the eval() function to run it; see here for an example: http://www.danielsadventure.info/Javascript/Javascript.html

```
<input
    type='button'
    value='Run Code'
    onclick="eval(document.getElementById('txtCode').value);" />
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, this iv very helpful

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Please don't forget to click the check mark next to the best question so that people know that this question is answered.

Comment: Sorry, I am new in StackOverflow and not sure where is this checkmark. Would you be so kind to share a screenshot?

Comment: You have to be logged in.  Next to each answer, there is a big number with an up arrow, and down arrow, and a checkbox.  You can click the checkbox next to the best answer to mark your question as answered so that people know not to try to answer it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JQuery terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/). It's quite flexible. Take a look specially to [this](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#multiple_interpreters) example.